# Draw equidistant points on a spiral

Tags: algorithm, draw, algebra, spiral

I need an algorithm to calculate the distribution of points on a spiral path.

The input parameters of this algorithm should be:

- Width of the loop (distance from the innermost loop)
- Fixed distance between the points
- The number of points to draw

The spiral to draw is an **archimedean spiral** and the points obtained must be **equidistant** from each other.

The algorithm should print out the sequence of the Cartesian coordinates of single points, for example:

Point 1: (0.0)
Point 2: (..., ...)
........
Point N (..., ...)

The programming language isn't important and all help greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

I already get and modify this example from this site:

```
    //
//
// centerX-- X origin of the spiral.
// centerY-- Y origin of the spiral.
// radius--- Distance from origin to outer arm.
// sides---- Number of points or sides along the spiral's arm.
// coils---- Number of coils or full rotations. (Positive numbers spin clockwise, negative numbers spin counter-clockwise)
// rotation- Overall rotation of the spiral. ('0'=no rotation, '1'=360 degrees, '180/360'=180 degrees)
//
void SetBlockDisposition(float centerX, float centerY, float radius, float sides, float coils, float rotation)
{
    //
    // How far to step away from center for each side.
    var awayStep = radius/sides;
    //
    // How far to rotate around center for each side.
    var aroundStep = coils/sides;// 0 to 1 based.
    //
    // Convert aroundStep to radians.
    var aroundRadians = aroundStep * 2 * Mathf.PI;
    //
    // Convert rotation to radians.
    rotation *= 2 * Mathf.PI;
    //
    // For every side, step around and away from center.
    for(var i=1; i<=sides; i++){

        //
        // How far away from center
        var away = i * awayStep;
        //
        // How far around the center.
        var around = i * aroundRadians + rotation;
        //
        // Convert 'around' and 'away' to X and Y.
        var x = centerX + Mathf.Cos(around) * away;
        var y = centerY + Mathf.Sin(around) * away;
        //
        // Now that you know it, do it.

        DoSome(x,y);
    }
}
```

But the disposition of point is wrong, the points aren't equidistant from each other.

[image: Spiral with non equidistant distribution]

The correct distribution example is is the image on the left:

[image: Sirals]

Comment: When you say equidistant, do you meant a constant distance following a direct (straight line) path from one point to the next, or do you mean distance along the path of the spiral? (I'm guessing you probably want the latter, but the current phrasing sounds closer to the former).

Comment: Hi Jerry. Thanks in advance. I mean constant distance along the path of spiral. I think that both distance are similar, but the distance along the curve is more accurate. (MAYBE!)

Comment: [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/equations/ArchimedesSpiral/Inline3.gif) gives the equation for a length along the spiral. At least at first glance, rearranging that to get an angle for a given distance looks like fairly simple algebraic manipulation (though I suppose I could have missed something so it's harder than it look).

Comment: Thanks Jerry. Di you know how I can add the Wolfram concepts to my code? I updated the question :)

Comment: @JerryCoffin That webpage (actually I read this page: [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArchimedesSpiral.html)) gives s(theta) analytically but inverting it (to get theta(s)) analytically is quite difficult. One could either use root finding algorithm or some approximate interpolation function for this purpose I think. If I have time I will elaborate it in a separate answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To a first approximation - which is probably good enough for plotting blocks close enough - the spiral is a circle and increment the angle by the ratio `chord / radius`.

```
// value of theta corresponding to end of last coil
final double thetaMax = coils * 2 * Math.PI;

// How far to step away from center for each side.
final double awayStep = radius / thetaMax;

// distance between points to plot
final double chord = 10;

DoSome ( centerX, centerY );

// For every side, step around and away from center.
// start at the angle corresponding to a distance of chord
// away from centre.
for ( double theta = chord / awayStep; theta <= thetaMax; ) {
    //
    // How far away from center
    double away = awayStep * theta;
    //
    // How far around the center.
    double around = theta + rotation;
    //
    // Convert 'around' and 'away' to X and Y.
    double x = centerX + Math.cos ( around ) * away;
    double y = centerY + Math.sin ( around ) * away;
    //
    // Now that you know it, do it.
    DoSome ( x, y );

    // to a first approximation, the points are on a circle
    // so the angle between them is chord/radius
    theta += chord / away;
}
```

[image: 10 coil spiral]

However, for a looser spiral you will have to solve the path distance more accurately as spaces too wide where the difference between `away` for successive points is significant compared with `chord`:
[image: 1 coil spiral 1st approximation] [image: 1 coil spiral 2nd approximation]

The second version above uses a step based on solving for delta based on using the average radius for theta and theta+delta:

```
// take theta2 = theta + delta and use average value of away
// away2 = away + awayStep * delta 
// delta = 2 * chord / ( away + away2 )
// delta = 2 * chord / ( 2*away + awayStep * delta )
// ( 2*away + awayStep * delta ) * delta = 2 * chord 
// awayStep * delta ** 2 + 2*away * delta - 2 * chord = 0
// plug into quadratic formula
// a= awayStep; b = 2*away; c = -2*chord

double delta = ( -2 * away + Math.sqrt ( 4 * away * away + 8 * awayStep * chord ) ) / ( 2 * awayStep );

theta += delta;
```

For even better results on a loose spiral, use a numeric iterative solution to find the value of delta where the calculated distance is within a suitable tolerance.

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys. This algorithm is perfect for my needs!

Comment: For funs (not understanding it completely) Im trying to plot your first image, which values would be representable similar?

Comment: @Terence not sure exactly, but it's ten coils and you can play at http://jsfiddle.net/gjowrfcd/1/

Comment: you should probably also limit the delta angle to at most 1.0 or so, for better results at the end of the spiral.

Answer (score 8):

Contributing a Python generator (OP did not request any specific language). It uses a similar circle approximation as Pete Kirkham's answer.

`arc` is the required point distance along the path, `separation` is the required separation of the spiral arms.

```py
def spiral_points(arc=1, separation=1):
    """generate points on an Archimedes' spiral
    with `arc` giving the length of arc between two points
    and `separation` giving the distance between consecutive 
    turnings
    - approximate arc length with circle arc at given distance
    - use a spiral equation r = b * phi
    """
    def p2c(r, phi):
        """polar to cartesian
        """
        return (r * math.cos(phi), r * math.sin(phi))

    # yield a point at origin
    yield (0, 0)

    # initialize the next point in the required distance
    r = arc
    b = separation / (2 * math.pi)
    # find the first phi to satisfy distance of `arc` to the second point
    phi = float(r) / b
    while True:
        yield p2c(r, phi)
        # advance the variables
        # calculate phi that will give desired arc length at current radius
        # (approximating with circle)
        phi += float(arc) / r
        r = b * phi
```

Answer (score 5):

In Swift (based on liborm´s answer), taking the three inputs as OP requested:

```
func drawSpiral(arc: Double, separation: Double, numPoints: Int) -> [(Double,Double)] {

  func p2c(r:Double, phi: Double) -> (Double,Double) {
      return (r * cos(phi), r * sin(phi))
  }

  var result = [(Double(0), Double(0))]

  var r = arc
  let b = separation / (2 * Double.pi)
  var phi = r / b

  var remaining = numPoints
  while remaining > 0 {
      result.append(p2c(r: r, phi: phi))
      phi += arc / r
      r = b * phi
      remaining -= 1
  }
  return result
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I found this post useful, so I am adding a Matlab version of the above code.

```
function [sx, sy] = spiralpoints(arc, separation, numpoints)

    %polar to cartesian
    function [ rx,ry ] = p2c(rr, phi)
        rx = rr * cos(phi);
        ry = rr * sin(phi);
    end

    sx = zeros(numpoints);
    sy = zeros(numpoints);

    r = arc;
    b = separation / (2 * pi());
    phi = r / b;

    while numpoints > 0
        [ sx(numpoints), sy(numpoints) ] = p2c(r, phi);
        phi = phi + (arc / r);
        r = b * phi;
        numpoints = numpoints - 1;
    end

end
```