# drawing spiral using jquery - spot distance

Tags: javascript, jquery, spiral

I am trying to draw a spiral from divs using jquery. I have done a regular spiral so far and seems to work fine for me. However the next step is that I need this to have big distance between divs when it starts and smaller one as it goes. I know that I should add an extra variable that will do this but I do not know how to implement this.

Here is my code so far

```
var radius = 50;
var x0 = 300;
var y0 = 300;
var segment = 50;
var angle = 0;    

for (var i=0; i<=segment; i++){
  angle = angle + (Math.PI * 2) / 30;
  var x=x0+radius*Math.sin(angle);
  var y=y0+radius*Math.cos(angle);
  $("#terrain").append("<div class='drag' style='top:"+ y +"px;left:"+ x +"px;'></div>")
  radius = radius + 5;   
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alvertos/v7avLbej/5/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make the size of each div a function of the radius.  One-seventh seems to work well:

```
size = radius/7;
$("#terrain")
  .append("<div class='drag' style='top:"+ y +"px;left:"+x+
          "px;width:"+size+"px;height:"+size+"px;'></div>"
         );
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z78bqf49/)**

---

**Edit**

Based on our comments, I now understand the problem better.  You could declare a `distance` variable, which is the distance between divs.  `angle` would then be updated as:

```
angle += distance/radius;
```

Each time through the loop, the distance would decrease, like this:

```
distance -= 1.5;
```

The rest of your code stays pretty much the same.

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fgx8d9jv/)

Comment: Thanks! Actually my idea is the reverse of what you have done. I want bigger divs when it starts and smaller ones as it goes. That's why I wanted big distance between divs in the beginning

Comment: I like @Gaby's answer a lot more than my own, but here's a Fiddle that has larger divs in the middle: http://jsfiddle.net/7vw4z76w/.  Is that more what you're going for?

Comment: I think @Gaby's answer is very similar to yours. The idea is pretty much the same. I think the hard part is to start with a large distance between the very first divs (so even if they are big they will not overlap each other) and as the spiral getting bigger this distance decreases.

Comment: the answer to this post might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13894715/draw-equidistant-points-on-a-spiral . however I can't still figure out how to use the variable chord which is the distance between the divs. so i could set a big value in the beginning and decreased it in every loop.

Comment: Ahh, when you wrote that the distance should be big at the beginning and small at the end, did you mean the distance between divs should always be constant?  See this fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/nLyk4vps/

Comment: And here's a version where the divs start out large and get smaller:  http://jsfiddle.net/vpuhg1fa

Comment: probably I didn't write this right, that's why you might have understood it incorrectly. By distance between divs I mean the distance between the **following** divs, not the distance between coils (as you did in your last fiddle)

Comment: Hmm, if none of my fiddles solve your problem, I may need to see an example to understand your goal.

Comment: here is a pic of a spiral that would work great for me. http://imgur.com/yfPd4H6 distance between div #1 and div #2 is the maximum one. distance between div #3 and div #4 is a little bit smaller etc. I hope this makes sense

Comment: Thanks a tone!!!!!!! That's it. I will try to center the first div a little bit however workjs great for me!!!!

Many thanks!!!!

Comment: Great, I've simplified the code and updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `transform:scale()` for sizing

```
var newitem = $('<div>',{
    'class': 'drag',
    css:{
        top:y,
        left:x,
        transform: 'scale('+ scale +')'
    }
});
$("#terrain").append(newitem);

scale += 0.02;
```

and when using this you should set the origin of the transformation at the center (*on CSS*).

```
transform-origin: 50% 50%;
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/v7avLbej/7/