Controlling Spacing in Spiral Hole Pattern Generation in Python
I'm facing an issue with my Python code. I'm trying to create a spiral of holes, but I want to control the spacing between the holes. Here's my current code:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import transform
import random
import time
import os
from skimage.transform import rescale, resize
from InputOutput.pagailleIO import saveEdf
import numba as nb

@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def create_holes(radius, height):
    patch_size = int(2 * radius + 1)
    x = np.arange(patch_size) - radius
    y = x[:, np.newaxis]
    dist = x**2 + y**2
    hole = np.where(dist < radius**2, 0, height)

    return hole

@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def generate_membranes(Nx, Ny, radius, height, output_path):
    hole = create_holes(radius, height)
    patch_size = hole.shape[0]

    image = np.full((Nx + 2 * patch_size, Ny + 2 * patch_size), height)

    theta_step = 0.0001  # Angular spacing between each hole

    theta = np.arange(0, max([Nx,Ny]) * np.pi, theta_step)
    r = radius * theta / np.pi * 1.414  
    x = np.floor(Nx // 2. + r * np.cos(theta))
    y = np.floor(Ny // 2. + r * np.sin(theta))

    x = np.clip(x, patch_size, Nx + patch_size - 1).astype(np.int32)
    y = np.clip(y, patch_size, Ny + patch_size - 1).astype(np.int32)

    for i in range(len(x)):
        if patch_size < x[i] < Nx + patch_size and patch_size < y[i] < Ny + patch_size:
            patchImage = image[x[i] - radius: x[i] + radius + 1, y[i] - radius: y[i] + radius + 1]
            if np.sum(patchImage) == height * patchImage.size:
                image[x[i] - radius: x[i] + radius + 1, y[i] - radius: y[i] + radius + 1] = hole

    return image

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    Nx = 1030  # Size in pixels in x
    Ny = 3000  # Total size
    radius = 2  # Radius in pixels
    hauteur = 0.00008  # Height in m
    Nx = Nx * 2
    h = hauteur * 1e6

    strPath = '/home/Bureau'
    
    image = generate_membranes(Nx, Ny, radius, h, strPath)

By increasing the theta_step parameter, I can adjust the spacing between the holes, but it creates disorder in the spiral, and the shape no longer resembles a spiral, I want the same constant spacing. Additionally, when I add a factor to the variable r (for example, r = radius * theta / np.pi * 1.414 * 2), it spreads the pattern, but not in both directions as I want.
What would be the best way to control the spacing between the holes constant while maintaining the spiral shape?
that's image I excepte to obtain : 
When I modifie theta_step I obtain :

Adding a factor of 2 in r obtain the good spacing only between spiral lines :

combing both : 
I would like to find a way to generate a spiral like the one expected, but with a larger and constant spacing between the holes while keeping the shape of a spiral. Unfortunately, as shown in the example, I do not get the desired result.

My question is as follows: I would like to find a way to generate a spiral like the one expected, but with a larger and constant spacing between the holes while keeping the shape of a spiral. Unfortunately, as shown in the example, I do not get the desired result. @JonSG

if you want constant spacing between "holes" you need to modify "theta_steps" as the radius increases, the reason you are seeing interesting  line patterns, is your code basically is saying I want a dot every x radians on a spiral
I would look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/13901170/7706256 for someone solving a similar problem, but, basically you need to decrease the angular "distance" between points as the radius of a point increases

theta_step ~ k/(2*pi*r)

My advice is to parameterize the spiral in terms of arc length instead of angle, and then just output the points by fixed arc length steps. I.e., find expressions (x(t), y(t)) for the points on the spiral, where t is the arc length. I guess the spiral you're showing is an Archimedean spiral -- a web search for "Archimedean spiral parametrize by arc length" finds some resources.

I can't see how to modify my code accordingly because the changes I make don't seem to affect anything.

@PortorogasDS remember not to ask your question in a comment: please [edit] your post and explicitly put your question in there.
